# Save a range of pages in a separate doc?

Tags: microsoft-word, save-as

I am working with Windows 8.1, x64 and Word 2013. Both of them are fully patched. I need to extract two pages from an existing word document.

If I were printing, I would be able to print only those pages in the print dialog. But the save dialog does not offer the functionality.

Googling is turning up [spurious noise](https://www.google.com/#q=microsoft+word+extract+subset+of+pages).

I can't simply copy/paste into a new document because of other problems with Word, like [How to make Word 2013 act like Word 2007 and honor profile settings?](https://superuser.com/q/875858/173513) and [Missing custom styles in Word 2013](https://superuser.com/q/875806/173513).

How do I save a range of pages in a separate doc?

Comment: You could save the current document with another name and *then* delete the parts you don't want.

Comment: You should be able to do this with Master Documents and subdocuments. At work at the moment, so don't have a lot of time to flesh out an answer, but take a look at the View > Outlining options.

Comment: The following macros shows how to break up a multipage document into separate files..  Check this article ; https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306348